# How to distribute the remainder of a division?

Tags: vb.net, distribution, modulo

I need to divide 23 students to 5 groups, so

```
Dim i as Integer = 23 Mod 5
```

gives remainder = 3.

How can I distribute the remainder such that the first, second, and third groups will have 1 member more than the others?

Or how to start distribution in reverse, where the fifth, fourth and third will have 1 extra member?

I want to get this values:

```
Dim groups(4) As Integer
groups(0) = 5
groups(1) = 5
groups(2) = 5
groups(3) = 4
groups(4) = 4
```

Comment: Too vague. Post your code.

Comment: Ok, I added the result I'm looking for.  How to do this I'm completely clueless.

Comment: How would you do this on a table using coins? *I have 23 pennies, and I need 5 piles. So I distribute 20 (5 piles of 4), and I hae a remainder of 3. Start at either end, take one from the remainder and add it to the pile. Do I still have more extras? If so, pick one up, put it on the next pile. Do I still have more? Repeat.* The logic is exactly the same, using a loop. What specific part of that are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Using physical coins it's easy practical knowledge.  The difficult part is how to code which I was asking how to.  How do I tell VB to count coins?  Good thing Blorgbeard has the solution.

Comment: There are several approaches to solving this, depending on your objectives. http://www.ctl.ua.edu/math103/apportionment/appmeth.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's your setup:

```
Dim groups As Integer() = New Integer(4) {}
Dim students As Integer = 23
```

You know how to calculate the group size and remainder:

```
Dim groupSize As Integer = students \ groups.Length     ' \ is integer division
Dim remainder As Integer = students Mod groups.Length
```

Then go through each group and assign the size to it:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To groups.Length-1 
    groups(i) = groupSize
Next
```

Finally, you need to distribute the remainder. According to your question, you want to add 1 to the first *remainder* number of groups.

Which translates to:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To remainder-1 
    groups(i) = groups(i) + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim value = 23
Dim divisor = 5
Dim remainder = value Mod divisor

Dim groups(divisor - 1) As Integer

For i = 0 To divisor - 1
    groups(i) = value \ divisor + If(i < remainder, 1, 0)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
Dim r As Integer = 23 Mod 5
Dim d As Integer = 23 \ 5
Dim group(4) As Integer
For i = 0 To group.Length - 1
    group(i) = d
    If r > 0 Then
        group(i) += 1
        r -= 1
    End If
Next
```